# WordPress plugin admin ajax not working anymore

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

So I have made a WordPress plugin and in the admin page I use an ajax call. It works fine on all my testsites and servers, but now I testing it on a bigger site with multiple other plugins installed. I don't know why but if I press the button that calls the ajax request, nothing is happening.

Here is the code for my ajax call:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "../wp-content/plugins/autocommerce/admin/activatePlugin.php?activate=true",
    method: "POST",
    data: { txtAC : txtAC, txtKey: txtKey }
}).done(function(msg) {
    if(msg == "success") {
        jQuery("#admin_activate").append('<input type="hidden" name="txtActivated" value="true" />');
        jQuery("#admin_activate").submit();
    } else if(msg == "failed") {
        jQuery("#activateError").html("Gegevens onjuist. Controleer uw gegevens en probeer het opnieuw.");
    } else if(msg == "notSet") {
        jQuery("#activateError").html("Een of meerdere velden zijn onjuist ingevuld.");
    } else {
        alert(msg);
        jQuery("#activateError").html("Er is een fout opgetreden. Probeer het later opnieuw.");
    }
});
```

There is no error and on the other sites its just working, so I have no idea where to start looking to solve this problem.

I hope anyone could help me out.

Comment: Check if your script is really accessing your indicated url url: "../wp-content/plugins/autocommerce/admin/activatePlugin.php?activate=true"

Comment: How could I test this? because on other sites I test it on, the code works fine.

Comment: hardcoded url in js is not the best idea I think. Better to add something like <script> var yourUrl = "<?php echo plugins_url(); ?> /autocommerce/admin/activatePlugin.php?activate=true"; </script> in php file of the page that is generating the ajax call and in the ajax call use yourUrl variable

Comment: You're right. It is a better idea. but still nothing is happening. I'm sure that the url is oke now

Comment: Try directly accessing your url to see if it is giving you any results. Also try indicating the data type in your ajax call, that might be a problem. Also check permissions of that php file. Are they 664 or 644?

Comment: The files all have protocol 644. I now see that I get a 403 forbidden error. So I will look if it has something to do with other plugins on that site, or the .htaccess

Comment: For some reason the htaccess denies all access to any .php file.

Comment: I have posted an answer with better solution for you. Using standard wordpress method will make it much easier and besides it is always better to follow best practices :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using wordpress standard ajax for that instead of making an ajax call to your own php file:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_yourfunction', 'yourfunction');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_yourfunction', 'yourfunction');

function nsds_change_password() { 
//your functional part goes here
}
```

Anf then in ajax call use admin ajax url which can be output beforehand like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'> var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>"; </script>
```

and the use ajaxurl as a variable and set additonal action parameter wich will be your function name.

Comment: Thanks I will try to use this way. Didn't know there was a standard wordpress ajax way :)

Comment: Did this work @WouterdenOuden?
Perhaps you wanna take a look at my question @Nick Surmanidze.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47219525/admin-ajax-php-not-working-in-new-wordpress-version

Comment: @WosleyAlarico I haven't used this code actually, because for some reason my jquery ajax worked again. I'm not sure what my problem was, but you should definitely try this answer. Hopes it works for you

Comment: I found out that the problem has nothing to do with ajax, but a problem in a meta query when I update to 4.8.3 version